# How to set toolbar title in center in android in JAVA

Tags: android

I know the layout way to set toolbar title in center. (Have a TextView in Toolbar)

I am looking for java way for same. 
This is my toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is how i am setting toolbar title in activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MY ORDERS");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Title is left aligned by default.

Is there any way (without changing layout) to make title centered aligned?

Comment: If you can check the question i have clearly mentioned JAVA way. The possible duplicate you mentioned providing a way in layout file to solve the problem

Comment: @DanielNugent Added Toolbar layout in question.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar widget can have child views, which can be used to customize the look and feel of Toolbar. ***The way to center text will be to use TextView as child of Toolbar***, and then customizing it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```